# Purchase specific product only once on woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want a specific product to be purchase only once. When customer A bought the product once, customer A will not be able to purchase it again. But other customers can still purchase the product..

Comment: Try using the `woocommerce_add_to_cart` filter on your cart. Within this you can check if the item has been purchased by  a customer or not and then reject the item if its been purchased. This is assuming you have means to verify the customer before he buys the product.

Answer (score 0):

A work around would be to use a coupon that reduces the price significantly. You can choose for coupons to only be used once per person